# How to check against a value range in a mapping table?

Tags: r, dplyr

Inputs:

```
library(dplyr)
A <- data_frame(Type=c("A","A","B"),R=c(3, 7, 12), Value = c(120, 130,300))
A
   Type     R Value
  (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
1     A     3   120
2     A     7   130
3     B    12   300
```

Mapping dataset:

```
Mapping <- data_frame(Type=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"), Rmin =     c(1,6,11,1,6,11), Rmax = c(5,10,15,5,10,15), Threshold = c(50,100,200,50,200,300))
Mapping

   Type  Rmin  Rmax Threshold
  (chr) (dbl) (dbl)     (dbl)
1     A     1     5        50
2     A     6    10       100
3     A    11    15       200
4     B     1     5        50
5     B     6    10       200
6     B    11    15       300
```

Output are expected to get with following step.

1. With the same Type value among A and Mapping, find the threshold value for the entry that has R >= Rmin and R <= Rmax. For example, for row 1 table in A, the threhold should be 50 (1<=3<=5, and type A).
2. isAbove value is obtained by assigning `isAbove <- 120>=50`

As a result, the expected output is:

```
B <-  data_frame(Type=c("A","A","B"),R=c(3, 7, 12), Value = c(60, 90,250), isAbove = c(T,F,F))
 B

    Type     R Value isAbove
   (chr) (dbl) (dbl)   (lgl)
 1     A     3    120    TRUE
 2     A     7    130   TRUE
 3     B    12    300  FALSE
```

Comment: Two questions for clarification: (1) How does `Value` need to change? there seems no logic behind it. (2) For the 2nd row in `B`, `isAbove` should be `TRUE` because `130` is above `100` for the matching row in `Mapping` (which is row 2). Isn't it?

Comment: @jaap, thanks for pointing them out. (1) there was a typo in `Value` column. ```Value``` column in B should be copied from A. (2) you're alright. updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the non-equi join capability of `data.table` is perfectly suited for that. Using:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(A)
setDT(Mapping)

A[Mapping, on = .(Type, R > Rmin, R < Rmax), isAbove := Value > Threshold]
```

gives you:

> ```
> > A
>    Type  R Value isAbove
> 1:    A  3   120    TRUE
> 2:    A  7   130    TRUE
> 3:    B 12   300   FALSE
> ```